# Multiple inheritance check if same object if only base classes are given

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have a method which takes two objects (which are not directly related to each other). Is it possible to check if the two objects are derived from the same object?

Given the following two interfaces and a class implementing both interfaces:

```
class InterfaceA {
  virtual void methodA() = 0;
};

class InterfaceB {
  virtual void methodB() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public InterfaceA, public InterfaceB
{
  virtual void methodA() override {}
  virtual void methodB() override {}
}
```

At a method which takes `InterfaceA a` and `InterfaceB b` as parameters, is it possible to check if `a` and `b` are the same object (e.g. `Implementation` or some other object which implements both interfaces).

For example:

```
bool isSameObject(InterfaceA& a, InterfaceB& b) {
  if(&a == &b) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

Implementation impl;
isSameObject(impl, impl); // should be true

Implementation impl2;
isSameObject(impl, impl2); // should be false
```

Comment: No, this is not possible in C++, as described. The only possible workaround would be if both interfaces are virtual, by using `dynamic_cast`, and making very, very careful notes.

Comment: `// some pure virtual methods` - the classes have virtual interfaces.

Comment: Does `i f(&a == dynamic_cast<InterfaceA *>(&b))` work for you? I wonder why you need this.

Comment: Well, in this case, see if a dynamic_cast on one returns a pointer to the other one.\

Comment: "check if the two objects are derived from the same base class" and "check if a and b are the same object" are two very different things. Please decide which one you want.

Comment: In case it helps: `dynamic_cast<void*>(&a)` produces a pointer to the most-derived object of which `a` is a base class subobject. So in your example, `isSameObject` can probably be implemented as `return dynamic_cast<void*>(&a) == dynamic_cast<void*>(&b);` Assuming I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve; it's not entirely clear.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI thank you I meant if a and b are the same object. Updated the question

Comment: @IgorTandetnik unfortunately this leads to `error: cannot ‘dynamic_cast’ ‘& a’ (of type ‘class InterfaceA*’) to type ‘void*’ (source type is not polymorphic)`
I would like that a single implementation `Implementation impl;` leads to true when passed into `isSameObject(impl, impl)`.

Comment: The idea behind my question is, that ìsSameObject` is some kind of error check. There are already many objects in the code base which implement both interfaces, however for some specific task I need the methods provided by both interfaces and don't want to enforce constrains on how the object is implemented (because there are different implementations available in the codebase). However I need to be sure that it's actually the same object (e.g. a voltageSensor which implements multiple interfaces)

Comment: @Leitwert: If "source type is not polymorphic", you don't have "some pure virtual methods"; that matters here.